# How to efficiently calculate $ax+b$ once I know $a$ and $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, computational-complexity

What's the cheapest way to calculate $ax+b$ several times once I know the values for $a$ and $b$?

For instance, the cheapest way to calculate $a + b +x$ several times, once I know the values for $a$ and $b$, is to calculate $K = a+b$ once, and then calculate $K + x$ as much as I need.

Is there a way to calculate $ax+b$ that is cheaper than performing a multiplication followed by an addition, once $a$ and $b$ are fixed?

Comment: Are you assuming $a, x, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: "calculate $ax+b$ several times"? Do you mean "multiply" $ax+b$ by itself several times? Because you just need to calculate one time, why would you calculate the same number several times?

Comment: if values x are iterated in sequence such as $x=0,1,2,...,n$, you could use $y_{n}= a+ y_{n-1} $where $y(0)=b$

Comment: What he want to do is set $\frac{y-b}{a}=x$.  He wants, knowing a,b, if there is a more efficient way to calculate $y=ax+b$ without first multiplying by $a$ and then adding $b$.

Comment: @Raj, yes. $a$, $b$ and $x$ are in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Integral, I mean to calculate it for several, different, unpredictable values of $x$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven, exactly as you said.

Comment: How do you define efficient? Are you looking for the method that uses the least possible number of binary operations? I don't get the question.

Comment: @math.n00b, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Your alternatives are:

1. Multiply by $a$ then add $b$.
2. Add $b/a$ then multiply by $a$.

If $x$ is a similar size to $b/a$ then you should choose 2.

If $x$ is very different in size to $b/a$ then you should choose 1.

It's not so much about efficiency as the precision that you could lose. Adding two numbers of very different size can lead to a loss of precision.